# Docker file, mysql, problem with privilages

Tags: mysql, docker

I have docker mysql, it is simple dockerfile, only COPY init.sql to docker-entrypoint-init.d, and there is also (in docker-compose) enviroment for password, root password, user pass and db name.

All works perfectly. But I have notification in workbench "Tables could not be fetched".

How can I add privilages in dockerfile?

Dockerfile-mysql:

```
FROM mysql:latest

COPY scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sql

EXPOSE 3306
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: a
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r
            MYSQL_DATABASE: dbb
            MYSQL_USER: b
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        restart: always
```

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile and docker-compose, otherwise people can't help you here.

Comment: Can you explain all that further? If you specified user and password, what else do you expect?

Comment: Everything is ok, but when I log on to workbench (I can using user "a" and pass "b" i see database, but there is an error: "Tables could not be fetched". And I dont see the data. In a user - there is no any priviligies. No select, update etc.

Comment: Does init.sql file is creating a default user for your docker databse, if so make sure your user had prevalidge to access data remotely?

Comment: No, there is only create table. I think environment properties create the database name, and the user.

Comment: Does you docker container on remote or you are working with local environment?

Comment: Hardly to say. I am using docker-toolbox. So it is no local, because has docker-machine ip. But it is on local machine.

Comment: Were u able to login mysql container and then to mysql?

Comment: Yes, I can. I can log on via root user like and standard user.

Comment: Run mysql_upgrade in your docker-container 
`docker exec -it container_name bash -c "mysql_upgrade -uroot -proot"`

root must be your mysql username and password